# Simplifying a Vector Integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, integration, calculus

This question has (long) remained unanswered on MSE. While reading the book - *Theory and Applications of Boltzmann Transport Equation* by Cercignani, I found this integral which I am unable to understand. Note that $\xi_i , \xi_l$ and $x_i , x_l$ are vectors. The first term in the simplification comes from the fact that $x_i$ is not equal to $x_l$, and we are differentiating $P_N$ wrt $x_i$ (over which we do not integrate) ; so the differentiation can be taken out of the integral. However the domain of integration has boundaries $|x_i-x_l|= \sigma $ which depend upon $x_i$, so there is some second term. This is the image: 
[image: Integral]

My question is: where does the second term come from? This book is mathematically very involved (for e.g. it uses at some places, volume and surface area of $n>3$ dimensional spheres) and its seems that I need to have some background/prerequisite for reading this book. I'll be very grateful if someone can suggest a maths book as prerequisite based on what I told you and which will help me to understand the integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need a higher dimensional version of the Leibniz rule to differentiate under the integral sign. Suppose you have an integral of this kind

$$
\int_{\Omega(s)} f(s,\vec x) \, d\vec x
$$

That's it, your region of integration and your function depends of a parameter $s$. (in your case $s = x_i$). Then if you want to calculate

$$
\frac{d}{ds}\int_{\Omega(s)} f(s,\vec x) \, d\vec x
$$
You get two terms, one that measures the change in the integrand and other that measures the changes in the domain (that also depends of $s$)

$$
\frac{d}{ds}\int_{\Omega(s)} f(s,\vec x) \, d\vec x = \int_{\Omega(s)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial s}(s,\vec x) \, d\vec x + \int_{\partial\Omega(s)} f(s,\vec x) \,\frac{\partial}{\partial s} d\sigma(s) 
$$

Where $d\sigma(s)$ is the area element in the boundary $\partial\Omega(s)$ for given $s$. Note that this last integral is with one dimension less that the other (is a boundary term). Now putting this last term in the other side
$$
 \int_{\Omega(s)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial s}(s,\vec x) \, d\vec x=\frac{d}{ds}\int_{\Omega(s)} f(s,\vec x) \, d\vec x  - \int_{\partial\Omega(s)} f(s,\vec x) \,\frac{\partial}{\partial s} d\sigma(s) 
$$
And this is the identity the book is using, with $s=x_i$ and $\Omega(s)$ what they state. Look at this wiki page for more information http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign#Higher_dimensions